How to combine type hint using bound type variable and static types for maximum flexibility?
I would like to add type hints to a simple function. Since it internally only uses numpy calls, it is very flexible with its inputs. Basically, it accepts all array-like objects, for which there is the numpy.typing.ArrayLike type.
Defining the return type is not as straight forward however. For some input types like lists, the numpy functions casts the return to a numpy array, which means I could use -> np.NDArray.
Some other input types like pandas.DataFrames, which I use heavily in my code. This would usually be a good reason to use a TypeVar bound to the input type.
How do I keep the flexibility of numpy while also providing meaningful type hints, for example for mypy?
Note: The example method is used to calculate sound pressure levels.
Both code snippets are perfectly viable code, the methods only differ in their type hints.
They cause different errors with static type checkers, demonstrating the limits of each approach.
Version 1:
def get_decibels1(p2: npt.ArrayLike) -> npt.NDArray:
    return (10 * np.log10(np.divide(p2, 4e-10)))

df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
get_decibels1(df).columns
# --- Causes mypy Error:
# error: "ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]" has no attribute "columns"  [attr-defined]

Version 2:
T = TypeVar('T', bound=npt.ArrayLike)
def get_decibels2(p2: T) -> T:
    return (10 * np.log10(np.divide(p2, 4e-10)))

ls = [4.0, 5, 6]
get_decibels2(ls).shape
# --- Causes mypy error:
#  error: "list[float]" has no attribute "shape"  [attr-defined]

How do I sensibly combine the two approaches?

Update:
I figured that I maybe can approach this with @overload. But this does not seem to work either, as the signatures overlap.
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Union[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series])
@overload
def get_decibels(p2: T) -> T: ...

@overload
def get_decibels(p2: npt.ArrayLike) -> npt.NDArray: ...

def get_decibels(p2: npt.ArrayLike):
    return (10 * np.log10(np.divide(p2, 4e-10)))
# --- Causes mypy error:
#  error: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types  [overload-overlap]

I was under the impression that mypy just chooses the first signature that matches, which would have solved it. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Turns out, the update was already 95% there: Mypy and other typechecker do read overloaded functions in the order they are defined, using the first one that matches.
By default, it will point out overlaps, as they are deemed unsafe (see mypy doc). However:

Note that in cases where you ignore the overlapping overload error,
mypy will usually still infer the types you expect at callsites.

So using type: ignore[overload-overlap] results in the expected behaviour.
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Union[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series])
@overload
def get_decibels(p2: T) -> T: ...  # type: ignore[overload-overlap]

@overload
def get_decibels(p2: npt.ArrayLike) -> npt.NDArray: ...

def get_decibels(p2):
    return (10 * np.log10(np.divide(p2, 4e-10)))

ls = [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(ls)

reveal_type(get_decibels(ls))
>>>note: Revealed type is "numpy.array[Any, numpy.dtype[Any]]"

reveal_type(get_decibels(df))
>>>note: Revealed type is "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame"


The reason it is deemed unsafe, is a situation where the calling code is already somewhat mislabeled.
df: np.ArrayLike = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
get_decibels(df)  # mypy will wrongly deduce the return type to be `np.NDArray`

Since I deem this to be somewhat of an edge case, this seems to be a good compromise to add type hints to this method. Especially since pd.DataFrame behaves like a np.NDArray in most cases anyway.

Personally, I'd rather have the function return a single type (NDArray) in all cases by applying numpy.array or numpy.asarray. Moreover, I believe np.divide(a, b)  and a/b are equivalent and finally, why overwrite a pandas.DataFrame when you can just extend the table? (if you have memory issues, then I understand and you might want to check out the polars library). Also, do you not need clip_db?
Although it is of personal taste, here goes my suggestion with a function that always returns a numpy array:
import numpy as np
from numpy import typing as npt
import pandas as pd

def get_decibels(p2: npt.ArrayLike) -> npt.NDArray:
    p2 = np.asarray(p2)
    return 10 * np.log10(p2/4e-10)

def get_decibels_clip(p2: npt.ArrayLike, clip_db: float=0) -> npt.NDArray:
    p2 = np.asarray(p2)
    return np.maximum(10 * np.log10(p2/4e-10), clip_db)  # is this what was asked? 

df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
df[["db1", "db2", "db3"]] = get_decibels(df)
print(df) 


Thank you for the answer. I didn't mean to include clip_db in the example and removed it.
np.divide() works on list and other iterables, whereas / expects numpy arrays.
I would like to keep the structure of the DataFrame and just change the values. Of course I could cast the result, but then the index and columns would be lost.
This question really only concernes the type hints.

I that case, I would replace my np.asarray with a pd.DataFrame. Otherwise, depending on your python version, I would type hint npt.ArrayLike | pd. DataFrame. If that does not answer your question then I am of no help here, sorry.
